# Problem with computing numerical Gradient with Matlab

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I am playing with numerically computing gradient of some function in matlab, and I have this weird result which I could not figure why.

Here is my simple matlab code

```
v = 0:0.05:1;

[x,y]=meshgrid(v);
x = x';
y = y';

phi = sqrt((x-(1/6)*pi).^2+(y-(1/4)*pi).^2)-1/6-...
(1/30)*sin(5*atan((y-(1/4)*pi)./(x-(1/6)*pi)));

[px,py]=gradient(phi,0.05,0.05);


[C,h]=contour(x,y,phi);
clabel(C,h)
hold on
quiver(x,y,px,py)
hold off
```

When I run this code, this is what I get

[image]

I notice that in some region, the gradient vectors point in the direction of decreasing function value instead of increasing function value.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Do not transpose the matrices x and y.

Remove the statements:

x = x';
y = y';

See what happens.

Comment: now it works! However, what should I do if I want to transpose the matrices x and y? The reason why I transposed them initially was so that (x(i,j),y(i,j)) represents my position in i th column and jth row on my grid. For instance, (x(3,2),y(3,2)) = (0.1,0.05)

Comment: Using x' and y', it appears the gradient function is interchanging px and py. So use [py,px] = gradient(...).

Comment: Many thanks to you

Comment: You're welcome. Personally I would keep x and y unchanged so x increases with column index j and y increases with row index i -- but I'm not sure how you are orienting the coordinates. Either way it doesn't matter as long as you understand how gradient interprets the grid.